# Django/Python не переходит по ссылкам на html страницы. Как это исправить?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, веб-программирование

Хотел создать простую доску для объявлений (только начал изучать Django). Одним из заданий было создать несколько html страничек и одну базовую, где содержатся ссылки на них (причём в подсказке к решению было сказано, что для этого нужно отредактировать html документ)
[image: Структура проекта]

Страница со списком отлично загружается (advertisement_list.html), ожидалось, как и в примере, что при нажатии на ссылку в advertisement_list.html, будет произведён переход к страничке advertisement1.html, но этого не просисходит(((
Причём пробовал по всякому: указывать в href и "/advertisement1.html" и полный путь, но ничего не помогает. Ниже приведён фрагмент html код advertisement_list.html

```
<html>
<h2><a href="advertisement1.html"> Advertisement 1 </a></h2>
</html>
```

При нажатии на ссылку выскакивает 404 код
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как это исправить (2 день сижу и перепробовал все варианты. Работает, только если создать внутри board ещё приложение через startapp и сделать его таким же, как и advertisements)**

На всякий случай код urls.py и views.py из advertisements

**advertisements/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.advertisement_list, name='advertisement_list'),
]
```

**advertisements/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def advertisement_list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'advertisements/advertisement_list.html', {})
```

**board/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('advertisements/', include('advertisements.urls')),

]
```

Comment: Вам в шаблонах для генерации нужно использовать функцию `url`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, большое спасибо за ответ! А можно ли выполнить эту задачу как-то по-другому? Просто в этом задании не предполагалось использование языка шаблонов

Comment: ну, в учебных целях можно создать для каждого конкретного объявления отдельный `view`, например, который будет рендерить отдельный шаблон. Добавить каждый `view` в `urls` и вот ссылка в `urls` и будет той ссылкой, которую надо вставлять в шаблон.

Comment: `path('advertisement1', advertisement1)` - вот примерно так. advertisment_1 - это функция, которая будет рендерить ваш шаблон для конкретного этого объявления. А ссылка будет тогда `href="/advertisements/advertisement1"`

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, спасибо Вам огромное!!! Работает!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно написать контроллер (в терминологии джанго это `View`), который по аналогии со список будет рендерить шаблон конктерного объявления. Передать в этот `View` id или другой признак объявления, по которому вы выберет его из базы данных.

Затем пробросить в контексте в шаблон ваше объявление и в темплейте подставить в нужные места данные вашего конкретного объявления.

В списке `urls` создать пусть для рендера объявлений, в котором будет использоваться идентификатор (или использовать гет-параметр для этого).

А в генерации ссылок на странице со списком использовать тэг `url`.

Это если в общих чертах. Вопрос слишком обширный и в ответе придется написать чуть ли не весь код приложения, чтобы это было с примерами.